# Why doesn't my email input styling remain active after a value is entered?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a reservation form for this website. Both elements (Name and email) have the same class. The word 'name' and 'email' cover the full box and when I start typing they should transition up and stay there however the email one seems to come down even after I've typed something in the input box. The `input:focus~label` is the one that changes it. Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid rgba(225,225,225,0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.inputbox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

.inputbox label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.inputbox input:focus~label,
.inputbox input:valid~label {
    top: -4px;
}

.inputbox input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.inputbox .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    line-height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="formbox">
        <h2>Book A Table</h2>
        <form action="#">
            <div class="inputbox">
                <span class="icon">
                    <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
                </span>
                <input type="Full Name" required>
                <label>Full Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="inputbox">
                <span class="icon">
                    <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
                </span>
                <input type="Email" required>
                <label>Email</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*The input:focus~label is the one that changes it*" Well, no. `input:focus~label` _and_ `input:valid~label` are what apply the change to the `top` position. Debug your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering an issue due to the use of an email input field and not filling in a valid pattern. Here is the solution to this problem:

```
.inputbox input:focus~label,
.inputbox input:valid~label,
.inputbox input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
    top: -4px;
}
.inputbox input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

Be careful. Additionally, I've modified the input fields by changing the types and adding placeholders. Here's a complete example:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.inputbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.inputbox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.inputbox input:focus~label,
.inputbox input:valid~label,
.inputbox input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
  top: -4px;
}

.inputbox input:invalid {
  color: red;
}

.inputbox input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 35px 0 5px;
}

.inputbox .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  line-height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="formbox">
    <h2>Book A Table</h2>
    <form action="#">
      <div class="inputbox">
        <span class="icon">
          <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
        </span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
        <label>Full Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputbox">
        <span class="icon">
          <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
        </span>
        <input type="email" placeholder="" required>
        <label>Email</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```